# Crystal Report data loading from Dataset(.xsd) and WebService method

Tags: asp.net, web-services, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report document, when design the report I have connected the Database expert from asp.net's Dataset(.xsd),at run time loading the Dataset value from a Web Service method, the web service method returns a DataSet Object. Here is the code for report invoking,

```
rpt = new ReportDocument();
DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
ST2013.ChoWebServ Cho = new ST2013.ChoWebServ();
Ds = Cho.SalesDayBook("07/07/2012", "07/09/2012");
rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("../Chocolates/SalesDayBook.rpt"));
rpt.SetDataSource(Ds);
ReportViewer.Enabled = true;                       
ReportViewer.ReportSource = rpt;
ReportViewer.DataBind();
ReportViewer.EnableDrillDown = false;
ReportViewer.Visible = true;
```

I'm getting the following error when run the report,

> Logon failed. Details: crdb_adoplus : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error in FileC:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\SalesDayBook {B038BB50-51A1-4908-8613-7EF6591F7B26}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters

Please let me know what mistake I did?

Answer (score 0):

This is the main reason behind this error:

```
rpt.SetDataSource(Ds);
```

Pass `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`

I found it from [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1400127.aspx) (see the [last reply](http://forums.asp.net/post/4223232.aspx))

---

<sup>Though it's very late reply but may help future users.</sup>